# Does SQL Server Handle Views Differently Than Tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I ran into an interesting problem with a client, I sent over a .dll file that within had a SQL statement. When the client ran this SQL query within Management Studio the query ran without issue and returned the proper results, when he left it to SQL Server to run things with the sp_executesql command the following error was received:

> The conversion of the varchar value '201101456914' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded.

(The number in the error above is from a varchar column, why it's trying to convert it to an integer is a mystery). When he set up the data in a table and ran the query the same way (with sp_executesql) it worked perfectly fine.

Here is the query that ends up being fired with the sp_executesql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT OffBookAccountDescription, Value,    
  OffBookAccountId, DataAsOf FROM OffBook 
  WHERE OffBookCode = @code AND MemberNumber = @num',
  N'@num int,@code char(1)',@num=5555,@code='U'
```

This causes the error to appear in the view but not when fired on a table with exactly the same data. The number in the above error message corresponds to the OffBookAccountId field in the query.

Is there something that SQL Server does in the back end to handle views differently than tables?

Comment: Can you share a sanitized version of the view and the query?

Comment: The view is on the client's machine but I can share the query that's being used

Comment: @sfuqua it's been edited, have a look

Comment: `201101456914` more than `INT` maximum value is `4,294,967,295`

Comment: @tinka I know, but that number '201101456914' is from a varchar field, it should be treating it like text all the way through the process but it doesn't which is what I'm trying to figure out is why it doesn't.

Comment: Certainly nothing suspicious looking in that query. Seems there must be some implicit conversion in the view - unless the user is setting @num to 201101456914.

Comment: @sfuqua I had considered that myself :) but I was watching him do it via a GoToAssist session and it may be like you say, with the way the sp_executesql command works on views it may be trying to do some sort of implicit conversion when it sees data like that with all digits.

Comment: What is the datatype of MemberNumber in the table, and is it declared as anything different in the view?

Comment: The same thing can happen with a table. What is happening is the two queries are being optimized differently, and in one, the conversion of the integer is being attempted *before* those rows are filtered out. If you issue a recompile you could get the same problem with the table (or the problem may disappear from the view). A couple of workarounds: (1) if the column really only contains integers, declare the param as BIGINT instead of INT (2) use a CASE expression (3) use TRY_CONVERT (4) stop using a string column to store integers